# 3 fields to have each other SUM with left t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum

i have a table

```
id           value
ATK01         20
ATK02         20
FRM01         10
FRM02         10
CON01          5
CON02          5
```

i want it to become like this

```
ATK   FRM   CON
40    20    10
```

can anybody help me

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: @DalmTo i try with  
SELECT * FROM  
(  <br/>
SELECT LEFT(kode_barang, 3) AS kode_barang, SUM(harga) total  
FROM barang  
GROUP BY LEFT(kode_barang, 3))Q  
 PIVOT(SUM(total)  
       FOR kode_barang  
       IN ([ATK],[FRM],[CON])  
       )P  
  from M.Ali

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(id VARCHAR(10),value INT)
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
('ATK01',20),('ATK02',20),('FRM01',10),
('FRM02',10),('CON01',5),('CON02',5)
```

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT LEFT(id , 3) AS id, SUM(value) total
FROM @TABLE
GROUP BY LEFT(id , 3)
)Q
 PIVOT(
       SUM(total)
       FOR id
       IN ([ATK],[FRM],[CON])
       )P
```

**Suggested by Blue_Feet**

```
select ATK, FRM, CON
from
(
  select id = left(id, 3), value
  from @TABLE
) d
pivot
(
  sum(value)
  for id in (ATK, FRM, CON)
) piv
```

**Result Set**

```
╔═════╦═════╦═════╗
║ ATK ║ FRM ║ CON ║ 
╠═════╬═════╬═════╣
║  40 ║  20 ║  10 ║
╚═════╩═════╩═════╝
```

<kbd>[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/16252/1)</kbd>

Comment: There is no need for the aggregation in the subquery -  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/16252/1

Comment: what if i want to change that field name to become like this

Attack  Formula  Countdown
40      20       10

Comment: @user3287496: `SELECT ATK AS Attack, FRM AS Formula, CON AS Countdown FROM ...`?

Comment: no, i mean its continuation from the answer

Answer (score 1):

This is a special type of a PIVOT query:

```
select
   sum(case when id like 'ATK%' then value else 0 end) as ATK   
   sum(case when id like 'FRM%' then value else 0 end) as FRM   
   sum(case when id like 'CON%' then value else 0 end) as CON   
from tab
```

Comment: You are missing closing parenthesis of your SUM function

Comment: Thanks for spotting, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you only require totals for those exact 3 prefixes and that's all there is on the table (and you know this ahead of time) then I would use the query shown by dnoeth. However, if on your table you had two additional IDs, let's say DON01 and DON02, it would not compute a total for the 3 letter prefix DON. If your table has a variety of IDs and you want subtotals for all three letter prefixes, but don't want to determine what every unique 3 letter prefix on your table is every time you run the query, you won't be able to use that method.

This query: (note I am using an additional 2 rows with the "DON" prefix)

```
with tbl as(
select 'ATK01' as id, 20 as amt from dual union all
select 'ATK02' as id, 20 as amt from dual union all
select 'FRM01' as id, 10 as amt from dual union all
select 'FRM02' as id, 10 as amt from dual union all
select 'CON01' as id, 5 as amt from dual union all
select 'CON02' as id, 5 as amt from dual union all
select 'DON01' as id, 40 as amt from dual union all
select 'DON02' as id, 20 as amt from dual)
, sub as(
select substr(id,1,3) as id, sum(amt) as sum_amt
from tbl
group by substr(id,1,3)
)
select listagg(id,' | ') within group (order by id) as list from sub
union all
select listagg(sum_amt,' | ') within group (order by id) as list from sub
```

Results in:

```
LIST
ATK | CON | DON | FRM
40 | 10 | 60 | 20
```

At which point you can convert text to columns in Excel using the pipe character ( | ) as the delimitter, and you will get one column for every unique 3 letter prefix on the table (without you having to know what all the prefixes are on the table ahead of the time).

Of course, not knowing why you need to have the 3 letter prefixes as columns rather than rows, I don't know if this is suitable for you.

Note that the query I gave you uses the first block to put your values in and my 2 additional rows for illustration, so your actual query would just be the below (replacing "tbl" with your actual table name):

```
with sub as(
select substr(id,1,3) as id, sum(amt) as sum_amt
from tbl
group by substr(id,1,3)
)
select listagg(id,' | ') within group (order by id) as list from sub
union all
select listagg(sum_amt,' | ') within group (order by id) as list from sub
```

Comment: This won't work in SQL Server.